# where does the shell fall into the process hierarchy?

Tags: bash, scripts

When you open a new terminal, it becomes the parent process of all processes forked within it. But where does the bash shell, for example, fall into this process chain? Is its parent the terminal? Are all processes forked within the shell children of the shell? If so, then when I change shells, why do the processes still remain running? In short, where does the shell fall in the process hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the parent of the bash process is the terminal. You can see the process hierarchy using the `ps -aef` command:

```
$ ps -aef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
[...]
sylvain   3510  1862  2 22:02 ?        00:00:01 gnome-terminal
[...]
sylvain   3520  3510  0 22:02 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
sylvain   3587  3520  0 22:03 pts/1    00:00:00 sh
```

- PID: Process ID
- PPID: Parent Process ID

In this example I started a `sh` process (3587) from the `bash` shell (3520)

Comment: How come when I change the shell, the processes spawned within the shell remain alive though?

Comment: For example, when I run a process within tmux in zsh shell, then I switch to the bash shell, tmux and the process within it are still running. WHy didn't those processes get killed when I switched from zsh to bash?

Comment: You can't "replace" a shell by another one, actually both are separate processes.If you type `exit` in my example you'll come back to the bash shell.

Comment: Now when I exit, tmux continues running because it ignores nohup signal. Does that mean tmux and its processes are not children of bash or terminal?

Comment: You can have multiple bash processes running at the same time, the one who started tmux and a second one started by the zsh process (this one being a child of tmux)

Answer (score 1):

There is nice commands that can help you to understand things here: `pstree`.

Show the process tree of the current process (in a shell, `$$` is substituted with the PID of the shell):

```
(0)samsung-rmano:~% pstree -s $$
init───gdm───gdm-simple-slav───gdm-session-wor───init───gnome-terminal-───zsh───pstree
```

Showing PIDs:

```
(0)samsung-rmano:~% pstree -s -p $$
init(1)───gdm(1128)───gdm-simple-slav(1203)───gdm-session-wor(1933)───init(1955)───gnome-terminal-(2340)───zsh(23005)───pstree(23044)
```

The whole system process tree, with the current shell highlighted (open a very big terminal! --- the higlight is not visible here):

```
 (0)samsung-rmano:~% pstree -h 
 ...
 ├─gdm─┬─gdm-simple-slav─┬─Xorg───4*[{Xorg}]
 │     │                 ├─gdm-session-wor─┬─init─┬─Notifications_h
 │     │                 │                 │      ├─Translator
 │     │                 │                 │      ├─at-spi-bus-laun─┬─dbus-daemon
 │     │                 │                 │      │                 └─3*[{at-spi-bus-laun}]
 │     │                 │                 │      ├─at-spi2-registr───{at-spi2-registr}
 │     │                 │                 │      ├─darktable───47*[{darktable}]
 │     │                 │                 │      ├─dbus-daemon
 │     │                 │                 │      ├─dconf-service───2*[{dconf-service}]
 │     │                 │                 │      ├─dropbox───30*[{dropbox}]
 │     │                 │                 │      ├─evolution-calen───4*[{evolution-calen}]
 │     │                 │                 │      ├─evolution-sourc───2*[{evolution-sourc}]
 │     │                 │                 │      ├─firefox─┬─plugin-containe───10*[{plugin-containe}]
 │     │                 │                 │      │         └─43*[{firefox}]
 │     │                 │                 │      ├─gconfd-2
 │     │                 │                 │      ├─gnome-session─┬─deja-dup-monito───2*[{deja-dup-monito}]
 │     │                 │                 │      │               ├─gnome-shell─┬─alarmclock───3*[{alarmclock}]
 │     │                 │                 │      │               │             ├─cairo-dock───3*[{cairo-dock}]
 │     │                 │                 │      │               │             └─6*[{gnome-shell}]
 │     │                 │                 │      │               ├─tracker-miner-f───3*[{tracker-miner-f}]
 │     │                 │                 │      │               ├─tracker-store───7*[{tracker-store}]
 │     │                 │                 │      │               ├─update-notifier───3*[{update-notifier}]
 │     │                 │                 │      │               ├─vino-server───2*[{vino-server}]
 │     │                 │                 │      │               ├─zeitgeist-datah───10*[{zeitgeist-datah}]
 │     │                 │                 │      │               └─3*[{gnome-session}]
 │     │                 │                 │      ├─gnome-settings-─┬─syndaemon
 │     │                 │                 │      │                 └─4*[{gnome-settings-}]
 │     │                 │                 │      ├─gnome-shell-cal───4*[{gnome-shell-cal}]
 │     │                 │                 │      ├─gnome-terminal-─┬─gnome-pty-helpe
 │     │                 │                 │      │                 ├─slogger
 │     │                 │                 │      │                 ├─3*[zsh]
 │     │                 │                 │      │                 ├─zsh───man───pager
 │     │                 │                 │      │                 ├─zsh───python3
 │     │                 │                 │      │                 ├─zsh───pstree
 │     │                 │                 │      │                 └─3*[{gnome-terminal-}]
...
```